Question about the forgotten index
‎1‎: ‎The complement of a graph $G$ is a graph $‎\overline{‎G‎}‎$ on the same vertices such that two distinct vertices of $‎\overline{G}‎$ are adjacent if and only if they are not adjacent in $G$‎.
2: For‏ a ‎graph ‎‎$‎G‎$ ‎its ‎forgotten ‎topologicalindex ‎is ‎defined ‎as:‎
‎$F(G)=‎\sum‎‎_{u\in V(G)}d‎_u‎^3 ‎=‎\sum‎_{uv\in E(G)}d‎_u‎^3=‎\sum‎_{uv\in E(G)}(d‎_u‎^2+d‎_v‎^2)$‎‎‎.
‎
I ‎obtained ‎an ‎extremum ‎value ‎for $F(G)+F(‎\overline{G}‎)‎‎$‎ ‎using ‎the ‎following effort.‎
‎
‎‎My effort:‎
$F(G)+F(‎\overline{G}‎)=‎\sum‎_1^n d_i‎^3+‎‎‎‎ ‎\sum‎_1^n‎\overline{d‎_i}‎‎^3=‎\sum‎_1^n ‎d‎_i‎^3+(n+1-d_i)‎^{3} =f‎\qquad (1)‎‎‎‎‎$‎.
We know ‎‎‎$ ‎\sum ‎d_i‎= 2m = g$, where $m$ is the number of edges and $n$ is the number of vertex.
According ‎to ‎‎$‎‎\nabla f= ‎\lambda ‎\nabla g‎‎‎‎‎$‎‎,we ‎will ‎have‎ ‎$ 3d_i‎^{2}-3(n-1-d_i)‎^{2}=1 \lambda‎‎ $‎. ‎Since ‎$‎\lambda‎$‎ ‎is ‎constant‎, then $ d_1=d_2=‎\cdots ‎=d_n‎ $‎. So‎‎  $nd_i= 2m$ and $d_i=‎\dfrac{2m}{n}‎$‎. ‎‎By placing in (1), ‎We ‎will ‎have‎ ‎‎
‎$‎‎‎\sum‎_i^n(‎\dfrac{2m}{n}‎)‎^{3}‎+(n-1-‎\dfrac{2m}{n}‎)‎^{3} ‎=n(‎\dfrac{2m}{n}‎)+(n-1-‎\dfrac{2m}{n}‎)‎^{3} \quad (2)‎‎$‎.
‎
‎Question:‎
Acoording to the above extermum (2), I ‎want  ‎an ‎lower ‎and ‎upper ‎bond ‎on ‎$F(G)+F(‎\overline{G}‎)$. How can I write?‎
I mean,what can be the value of **  in ‎$ ** < F(G)+F(‎\overline{G}‎)< **$‎?‎

Why is $$\sum_{u\in V(G)}d_u^3=\sum_{uv\in E(G)}d_u^3=\sum_{uv\in E(G)}(d_u^2+d_v^2)\ ?$$ I find these identities hard to believe, but perhaps I misunderstand the notation.
